# CSS div size height autoadjustment

Tags: html, css

I have a div element containing a videoWrapper. What I want it to do is to be able to auto resize when I make the broswer's screen smaller. It works with the width because I could set a % to it. But I had to set a fixed value for the pixels.
So right now it auto adjusts the width but not the height, it stays always the same.

Here is the css style I am using for the div

```
height: auto;
height: 700px;
width: 70%;
border-style: solid;
border-color: red;
```

Comment: you could try setting height, min-height and max-height.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
<div class="videoWrapper">

<iframe width="560" height="349" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>

 .videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
 }
   .videoWrapper iframe {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not use the attribute height: 100%, it just did not work. I used the attribute height: 70vh, that solved my problem. Thanks anyway.